# Properly configuring mocha.json in visual studio for sails.js app testing

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, sails.js, mocha.js

I am trying to startup a new project node.js with proper testing and tools.
I choose the framework sails.js , I use travis as a my CI tool https://travis-ci.org/lomithrani/InteractiveResume.

I use npm to launch my test with this line in my package.json

```
"test": "mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js"
```

bootstrap.test.js:

```
var Sails = require('sails'),
    sails;

before(function (done) {

    // Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift.
    this.timeout(5000);

    Sails.lift({
    // configuration for testing purposes
    }, function (err, server) {
        sails = server;
        if (err) return done(err);
        // here you can load fixtures, etc.
        done(err, sails);
    });
});

after(function (done) {
    // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
    Sails.lower(done);
});
```

the test I use as a sample:

```
var request = require('supertest');

describe('ResumeController', function () {

    console.log('test');
    describe('#hi()', function () {
        it('should say hi', function (done) {
            request(sails.hooks.http.app)
                .get('/resume/hi')
                .expect(200, done);
        });
    });
});
```

So If I run npm test or on [travis](https://travis-ci.org/lomithrani/InteractiveResume) everything works fine. But running it within visual studio doesn't work. As , as far as I understand it only runs the *.test.js and not the bootstrap.test.js first. I get a undefined error on sails at sails.hooks.http.app the [official doc from github.com/Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Test-Explorer#configuring-mocha-for-vs) provide very little detail on the way to configure, only that I can create a mocha.json such as this one :

```
{
      "ui": "tdd",
      "timeout": 300000,
      "reporter": "xunit"
}
```

but I fail to see which element I could use of [https://mochajs.org/#usage](https://mochajs.org/#Usage)
in order to execute bootstrap first.
If you have any workaround to suggest or any Idea you are very welcome.

Here is the full stacktrace I get within visual

```
Test Name:  ResumeController #hi() should say hi
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result StandardOutput:  
1..1
not ok 1 ResumeController hi() should say hi
  ReferenceError: sails is not defined
      at Context.<anonymous> (C:\interactiveResume\test\unit\controllers\ResumeController.test.js:8:21)
      at callFnAsync (C:\interactiveResume\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:306:8)
      at Test.Runnable.run (C:\interactiveResume\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:261:7)
      at Runner.runTest (C:\interactiveResume\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:421:10)
      at C:\interactiveResume\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:528:12
      at next (C:\interactiveResume\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:341:14)
      at C:\interactiveResume\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:351:7
      at next (C:\interactiveResume\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:283:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\interactiveResume\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:319:5)
# tests 1
# pass 0
# fail 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the -r or --require flag.  Running directly from the command line will work.

However, that said, I'm pretty sure that the visual studio mocha.json options file doesn't support the require flag properly.  Also, they haven't documented which flags are supported and which ones aren't.  I've done some experimenting with modifying mocha.js in the Program Files Node.js Tools for Visual Studio folder and it looks like it only accepts certain flags where functions are already predefined in the mocha npm package.

Either way, even if you did modify this file and make it work, next time you upgrade your visual studio node.js tools, your changes would probably be blown away.  There just isn't good support or documentation for this yet.  I wish I didn't have a team of developers demanding all the tests worked certain ways in visual studio, otherwise I'd just use visual studio code.

I'm guessing they'll take pull requests on the mocha.js file though if you can get it working.  I just don't have the time to look into it too much.